# Proceedings booktitle not appearing in Springer Nature template

Tags: bibliographies, springernature

I am submitting a paper to a Springer journal using their LaTeX template available [here](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support). I am using the Standard Nature style `(sn-standardnature.bst)`.

Everything works fine except that my `InProceedings` references do not seem to be appearing correctly in my bibliography. From my reading, I have included all required fields for `InProceedings`, those being the authors, title, booktitle and year. Despite the fact that I have the booktitle field, it does not appear in the reference. An example output would be:
"Smith, J. *Article Title* (2021)." where I am wanting: "Smith, J. *Article Title*. Book Title (2021)."

By experimenting I found that including the editor field would partially resolve the issue (although it would include the blank editors field in the reference itself, which I do not want).

When compiling I also get the warning:

*"You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry myproceedings while executing---line 1701 of file sn-standardNature.bst"*.

I have followed this up but have been unable to find how to resolve my specific issues, although judging by similar answers on this site [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325021/254294), [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482872/254294), [[3]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464168/254294), I suspect it may be to do with an errant `skip$` command in the `sn-standardnature.bst` file.

```
\documentclass[sn-standardnature]{sn-jnl}
\begin{document}
    Words1 \cite{myproceedings}
    \bibliography{ABC}
\end{document}
```

Where an example of my `InProceedings` bibtex entry is:

```
@InProceedings{myproceedings,
  author =   {Smith, J.},
  title =    {Article Title},
  booktitle = {Book Title},
  year =     {2021}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the editor of the book.

[image: zz]

```
\documentclass[sn-standardnature]{sn-jnl}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @inproceedings{myproceedings,
        author = {Smith, J.},
        title = {Article Title},
        editor = {Zaimis, E.},
        booktitle = {Book Title},
        year = {2021}
    }       
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    Words1  \cite{myproceedings}

    \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

As a help to solve other similar issues I wrote this guide:

**(1)** Download [Springer Nature LaTeX authoring template](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support)

**(2)** Add the missing extension (!) `.zip` to the downloaded file and open it. The package contains the  `sn-bibliography.bib` with 12 references from various sources.

**(3)** Make a directory including `sn-bibliography.bib`,  `sn-jnl.cls` and, for example `sn-standardnature.bst`, (found in the subdir `bst` together with other formats).

**(4)** Save this file in the same directory and compile:

LaTeX +  LateX + bibtex + LateX + LateX

```
\documentclass[sn-standardnature]{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}        
Testing  \texttt{sn-bibliography.bib}   \cite{bib12}

\nocite*

\bibliography{sn-bibliography}  
\end{document}
```

**(5)** After `bibtex` you shold see in the command window

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.3)
The top-level auxiliary file: Testingbib.aux
The style file: sn-standardNature.bst
Database file #1: sn-bibliography.bib
Process exited normally
```

The last line is important.

**(6)** The output should look like this:

[image: z]

**(7)** Now you know your installation is fine and you are able to produce the list of references.

**(8)** Finally replace `sn-bibliography.bib` with your own `.bib` file, put your `\cite` and go to step **4**.

**(9)** If after running `bibtex` you get `Process exited with error(s)` you can use the .bib template as a guide to found missing fields, proper format for entries and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I exactly have the same setup but the cite still does not appear in the text and I still get `?` in the text.

Comment: @ARAT  After bibtex compile twice.

Comment: Okay it worked but this time `\citep{...}` and `\citet{...}` do not do what they are supposed to do. They print out numbers wrapped around square brackets. By the way, I am using Overleaf.

Comment: @ARAT It will be best to ask a new question  showing a complete compilable code. (The preamble it is very important for the output)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by replacing `booktitle` with `series` in your `.bib` entry.